# Method code too large in Groovy & Grails?

Tags: grails, groovy, jvm

```
2014-06-17 11:22:18,622 [Thread-11] ERROR compiler.GrailsProjectWatcher  - Compilation Error: startup failed:
General error during class generation: Method code too large!
```

What is the solution? Only 4-5 line code hide and restart then fully run in successfully, the bootStrap file size is 149k. When I comment or delete 4-5 line code, it will be run without no error!

Comment: Can you provide further information? Grails version, the code causing the problem...

Answer (score 13):

The Java Virtual Machine has a [limitation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.9.1) that methods cannot be larger than 64k (65536 bytes). This [post](https://web.archive.org/web/20200502032427/http://chrononsystems.com/blog/method-size-limit-in-java) describes this limitation in details.
The best way to overcome this issue is simply splitting your large method into smaller ones, which is generally a good practice.

Also notice that the JVM JIT compiler will not compile methods larger than 8K. You can however change this behavior using the [-XX:-DontCompileHugeMethods](http://blog.leenarts.net/2010/05/26/dontcompilehugemethods/) option.

Comment: any solution how I can get which class is having this issue

Answer (score 2):

**The problem:** Just got in Jenkins pipeline the following exception error: `org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
General error during class generation: Method code too large!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method code too large!`

**Explanation** : The root cause related to 64kB limit of byte code of a single method. Java Virtual Machine has implicit limitations on class that there are mandatory to be followed and restricted according to performance and the language limitiation - such as: size of an operand stack in frame, length of fields and method names, number of methods may be declared in class etc... you can follow this "check list" on [Oracle JVM documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.11). You got the *method size limitation on this scenario*.

**Solution**: In order to solve this issue, just separate the class methods into shared-lib library or sub internal / external class (such as `Utils.Groovy` for example) and import that library in your main class. In general a code should be readable , lean and high level. if it's too long export the functionality use object oriented architecture and you would earn readable and maintainable code as well.