# Grails gsp file too large. "Method code too large!" Runtime error

Tags: grails

I have a gsp file with 1800 lines of code and couple of templates that are rendered from this view. The view worked perfectly before i added a couple of if conditions.

The stacktrace follows:

```
Compilation error compiling GSP [file_gsp]:startup failed:
General error during class generation: Method code too large!

java.lang.RuntimeException: Method code too large!
```

Comment: http://www.slideshare.net/burtbeckwith/grails-worst-practices. 23. Do a lot of work in GSPs. Eventually you'll hit the maximum GSP size limit, but that's a problem for later (in your case now :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make parts of gsp file as templates based on its behavior. it worked for me once or try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24256316/method-code-too-large-in-groovy-grails)