# Groovy compilation is failing with Method code too large

Tags: java, grails, groovy, compiler-errors, jvm

I have got two code base to merge in one, I did this exercise. However, compilation is failing with below error. I have already gone through few links and it seems no concrete solution is available.

**My Issue is:**
How I can identify which Groovy class is throwing this error as its generic error without any information. I have thousands of classes and few of them I have already corrected but still issues are happening. I am like to lost into it and seeking help.

Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method code too large!
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.MethodWriter.a(Unknown Source)
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassWriter.toByteArray(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$16.call(CompilationUnit.java:815)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1055)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:591)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:569)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:546)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:525)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:122)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:47)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.CompilerDaemonServer.execute(CompilerDaemonServer.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:360)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

1 error

 FAILED
```

Few links which I have already gone through but it didn't help out
[Method code too large in Groovy & Grails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24256316/method-code-too-large-in-groovy-grails)

As per oracle documentation a method size should not exceed 64K size and I am running this code in Ubuntu and tried all possible classes which is greater than 64K and started correcting one by one but I am getting 100+ classes and going through each is like boring and hectic as well.

Is there any tool or library through which I can get to know which class is having issues.

**Note:** I tried scanning through sonar/codenarc/clover but nothing worked out for me.

Comment: "Is there any tool or library through which I can get to know which class is having issues." - I think StackOverflow discourages questions asking for recommendations on tools.

Comment: Is having “two code base to merge” relevant to the problem? Do these codebases work in isolation without having this problem? Or did the original developer(s) create 100+ classes without ever testing them? Besides that, if the Groovy compiler produces errors without reporting the problematic class, I’d file a bug report to the Groovy compiler developers.

Comment: Jeff Scott Brown, thanks for your reply. I tried all possible ways as per my knowledge and looking for help here. Any recommendation or suggestions may help me.

Comment: Holger - Actually one project we team has initiated a year back from taking core development branch(core product) now project has been completed and all the code we need to merge back to core product. These two codebase worked individually without any issues. While merge many files have size more than expectation.. its not an issue with groovy.. i believe this issue is related to some function which have now size more than expected ..

Comment: That raises questions about how that merging works. Normally, when putting the classes of two projects into one, just the number of classes grows. Or, if truly two classes are merged into one, the number of methods within that class would grow. But how does the code of a method become too large? Did you literally merge multiple methods into one large method? How does that make sense, semantically?

Answer (score 0):

Simple try/catch helps. Also do println along the callflow to see where flow stops in call (ie filter -> interceptor -> controller -> interceptor )

Comment: thank you for your reply. I guess compiler is not reaching up to each line code as I have put many println just to get the cause but nothing is getting printed. What I have observed is if any code issue (compilation issue) its throwing exception. However if no code issue then I am getting only 'Method code is too large'.

Comment: Yeah sounds like a compiler issue in which case you need to increase the ram in your GROOVY_HOME or JAVA_HOME or wherever you are setting it.

Comment: I already tried increasing java memory, let me try once again.