# Micronaut test @MockBean not working for AWS S3Client

Tags: java, amazon-s3, groovy, spock, micronaut

I have been trying to test a service class which has [S3Client](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Client.html) as dependency. When I'm running the test getting below error.

**Error:**

```
Groovyc: Error generating bean definition class for dependency injection of class [software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client]: Method too large: com/example/service/impl/$TestServiceSpec$S3Client1$Definition$Exec.<clinit> ()V
```

**Service Class:**

```
@Slf4j
@Singleton
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {

    @Inject
    private final  S3Client s3Client;

    public TestServiceImpl(S3Client s3Client) {
        this.s3Client = s3Client;
    }

    @Override
    public void test() {
        log.info("Test Method");
    }
}
```

**Spock Specification:**

```
@MicronautTest
class TestServiceSpec extends Specification {

    @Inject
    TestService service

    @Inject
    S3Client s3Client

    @MockBean
    S3Client s3Client() {
        Mock(S3Client)
    }

    def "Test"() {
        when:
        service.test()
        then:
        noExceptionThrown()
    }
}
```

I also tried with [DetachedMockFactory](https://spockframework.org/spock/javadoc/1.1-SNAPSHOT/spock/mock/DetachedMockFactory.html)

```
@Factory
static class Mocks {
    DetachedMockFactory factory = new DetachedMockFactory()

    @Bean
    @Singleton
    @Replaces(S3Client)
    S3Client s3Client() {
        factory.Mock(S3Client)
    }
}
```

With `DetachedMockFactory` logic I'm getting below error

```
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.DependencyInjectionException: Failed to inject value for parameter [s3Client] of class: com.example.service.impl.TestServiceImpl

Message: No bean of type [software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).
Path Taken: TestServiceSpec.setService([TestService service]) --> new TestServiceImpl([S3Client s3Client])

    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.resolveBean(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:2087)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:1297)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2354)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2305)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2251)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3016)
    at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:80)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2918)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2879)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2800)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1617)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanResolutionContext.getBean(AbstractBeanResolutionContext.java:66)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.resolveBean(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:2065)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.getBeanForMethodArgument(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:1154)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.inject(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:621)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doInject(DefaultBeanContext.java:2716)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.inject(DefaultBeanContext.java:959)
    at io.micronaut.test.extensions.AbstractMicronautExtension.beforeEach(AbstractMicronautExtension.java:385)
    at io.micronaut.test.extensions.spock.MicronautSpockExtension.lambda$visitSpecAnnotation$5(MicronautSpockExtension.java:144)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:148)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.model.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:148)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.model.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:148)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at io.micronaut.test.extensions.spock.MicronautSpockExtension$1.proceed(MicronautSpockExtension.java:80)
    at io.micronaut.test.extensions.AbstractMicronautExtension.interceptEach(AbstractMicronautExtension.java:135)
    at io.micronaut.test.extensions.AbstractMicronautExtension.interceptTest(AbstractMicronautExtension.java:92)
    at io.micronaut.test.extensions.spock.MicronautSpockExtension.lambda$visitSpecAnnotation$0(MicronautSpockExtension.java:72)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.model.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:148)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NoSuchBeanException: No bean of type [software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2805)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1617)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanResolutionContext.getBean(AbstractBeanResolutionContext.java:66)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.resolveBean(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:2065)
    ... 73 more
```

Can someone help me, How to mock the S3Client Class.

Comment: Does it work in a simple spock test without all the injection stuff, e.g., just create a mock in a test and try to call methods on it?

Comment: @LeonardBrünings If i create mock manually without using `@MockBean` annotation it's working fine, But I need to inject the mock into service class. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Q & A for the first error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24256316/method-code-too-large-in-groovy-grails I believe you should try with a simple stub implementation of `S3Client`. BR

Comment: @RoarS. but here `S3Client` class is external dependency I can't split/change the code

Comment: Interface `S3Client` contains a lot of methods. If you're using just a few of these, I  believe  creating a thin wrapper around `S3Client` with an interface that specifies the methods you're using from `S3Client`, and inject the wrapper into TestService is the way to go. BR

Comment: @RoarS. I have already tried but it's not working, It's not even recognising that custom implemenation

Comment: Maybe you should try to follow the guide with some basic beans and see if you're able to make that work. See Using Spock Mocks here: https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/latest/guide/